# Laravel 4 password reminder: redirection issue

Tags: laravel-4, password-recovery

I'm using the Laravel 4 password reminder functionality, as described here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/security#password-reminders-and-reset. In order to generate the token, send the email and create de DB record in the password_reminder table, I use the standard code in my routes file :

```
Route::post('password/remind', function() {
  $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'));
  return Password::remind($credentials);
});
```

This code is suppose to send me *back* to my input form in case of any error (unknown email address for instance). Instead of that, I get a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. The reason is Laravel don't try to send me back to my form URL (which is `/password/forgot`): he tries to redirect me to `/password/remind`, in GET, and this route does not exist (of course) in my routes.php file.

I checked the code of the `Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\PasswordBroker` class, which is responsible of this redirection, and found out this method :

```
protected function makeErrorRedirect($reason = '')
{
  if ($reason != '') $reason = 'reminders.'.$reason;
  return $this->redirect->refresh()->with('error', true)->with('reason', $reason);
}
```

I replaced `$this->redirect->refresh()` by `$this->redirect->back()`, and everything is now working as excepted. But as I couldn't find any comment on this bug anywhere, I assume I'm doing something wrong… But I can't find what !

Here is my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('password/forgot', array('as' => 'forgot', 'uses' => 'SessionsController@forgot'));
Route::post('password/remind', function() {
    $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'));
    return Password::remind($credentials);
});
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', function($token) {
    return View::make('sessions.reset')->with('token', $token);
});
Route::post('password/reset/{token}', array('as' => 'reset', 'uses' => 'SessionsController@reset'));
```

my SessionsController relevant code:

```
class SessionsController extends BaseController {

    [...]

    public function forgot() {
        return View::make('sessions.forgot');
    }

    public function reset() {
        $credentials = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'password_confirmation' => Input::get('password_confirmation')
        );

        Input::flash();

        return Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password) {
            $user->password = Hash::make($password);            
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::to('home');
        });
    }

}
```

and finally my view code:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'password/remind', 'class' => 'form', 'role' => 'form', 'method'=>'post')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'E-mail') }}
        {{ Form::text('email', '', array('autocomplete'=>'off', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit("Envoyer", array("class"=>"btn btn-primary")) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: After Googling a bit, I found this: http://culttt.com/2013/09/23/password-reminders-reset-laravel-4/ In the first comments, they're getting the same error. Someone said that moving the routes from closures to controllers solved the error. Maybe you could try this and see what happens.

Comment: @ManuelPedrera Thanks for your advice. I tried that, without success…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible, I highly recommend you to upgrade to Laravel 4.1, because it comes with a more flexible (also easier to understand and to work with) solution for password remind/reset.

Check out this example with Laravel 4.1:

https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-4.1-Password-Resets/blob/master/app/controllers/RemindersController.php